# case insensitive glob listing in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have the following code:

```
    $ print -l backgrounds/**/*.((#i)jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|png|svg|xcf|cur|ppm|pcd)
```

the intention was to list some image file indifernet of the case of file termination.

But my code seems to not be functional because won't list files whit uppercase endings.
Can someone explain my error in the above code example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You need the `#i` to apply to everything, not just `jpg`.  You can use:

```
$ print -l backgrounds/**/*.(#i)(jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|png|svg|xcf|cur|ppm|pcd)
```

Make sure you have also done:

```
set -o extended_glob
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that using `#i` requires that `EXTENDED_GLOB` be set in your script/shell:

```
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
```

See the [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation), section *1.8.4 Globbing Flags*, or type `man zshexpn`.

And you want: `*.(#i)(jpg|gif|etc)`

Comment: Thanks all. Tried that code but without EXTENDED_GLOB and every time gave me errors. Now works.